# Как WordPress задать картинку для сайта при публикации?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста как Вордпрессе сделать, чтобы при публикации ссылки на сайт, появлялась нужная мне превьюшка-картинка ссылка ??

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос.

**Вариант 1**

Вам нужно использовать код для первью к каждому посту, к примеру:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="адрес где лежит картинка" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="какой заголовок выводить" />
<meta property="og:description" content="описание" />
<meta property="og:url" content="выводящаяся сссылка" />
```

**Вариант 2**

Найти необходимый плагин, их достаточно много.